# cant get the intent extras

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I used `putextras` to send data to other page

```
 Intent i = new Intent(Camerapage.this, Camera2.class);
      i.putExtra("mood","happy");
      i.putExtra("anger","anger");
      i.putExtra("fear","fear");
      startActivity(i);
```

and when i receive it

```
 mood.setText(intent.getStringExtra("mood"));
        happy.setText(String.valueOf(intent.getIntExtra("happiness",1)));
        fear.setText(String.valueOf(intent.getIntExtra("fear",1)));
         anger.setText(String.valueOf(intent.getIntExtra("anger",1)));
```

i tried to comment to know where it does crash ... it handels the "mood" value but it crashes when i ask for anger and fear ...

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
mood.setText(intent.getStringExtra("mood"));
    happy.setText(String.valueOf(intent.getStringExtra("happiness")));
    fear.setText(String.valueOf(intent.getStringExtra("fear")));
     anger.setText(String.valueOf(intent.getStringExtra("anger")));
```

Answer (score 0):

Change to `getStringExtra()` :

```
   mood.setText(intent.getStringExtra("mood"));
   happy.setText(intent.getStringExtra("happiness"));
   fear.setText(intent.getStringExtra("fear"));
   anger.setText(intent.getStringExtra("anger"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The `happiness` variable is is never set

```
happy.setText(String.valueOf(intent.getIntExtra("happiness")));
```

Also, you are sending `String` values, so use `getStringExtra()` instead of `getIntExtra()`

Answer (score -1):

At this line you are receiving a String:

```
 mood.setText(intent.getStringExtra("mood"));
```

But in this lines a String too, but you are tryin to get the values with `getIntExtra()` !

```
  happy.setText(String.valueOf(intent.getIntExtra("happiness",1)));
  fear.setText(String.valueOf(intent.getIntExtra("fear",1)));
  anger.setText(String.valueOf(intent.getIntExtra("anger",1)));
```

try changing this lines using `getStringExtra()`:

```
  mood.setText(intent.getStringExtra("mood"));
  happy.setText(intent.getStringExtra("happiness"));
  fear.setText(intent.getStringExtra("fear"));
  anger.setText(intent.getStringExtra("anger"));
```

and remember you are missing to send the `happiness` value from your `intent`

```
 i.putExtra("happines",":)");
```

Comment: Again wrong. `getStringExtra()` method does not take default value. Even if it took it would be a string and not int. And if you use `getStringExtra` there is no need for `String.valueOf`

Comment: I know that getStringExtra()  does not take default value, and String,valueOf() is not needed because you are getting a String value, i don´t understand why you write this comment.

Comment: Still editing were you? :) Your previous revision of answer did not suggest so.

Comment: Sure you can. Just don't say why you write this comment.Admit you are posting wrong answers and the nyou don't ack when someone corrects.  Also I see you deleted all my previous comments. You are misusing your power.

Comment: are you sure that this is a wrong answer? the next time i have remmember avoid post something until i finish my answer for people like you. (i can´t delete comments)